# how to Ranking of Employees based on supervisor id with dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table named 'DIM_Employee_Details' which contains Employee details along with supervisor id. Each employee has a supervisor. I am applying RLS based on employee id such that when an employee logs in, only the details of the employees who are under the same supervisor are shown. I want to display the rank of employees in descending order under a supervisor based on a measure. Kindly check the below measure used for ranking:

```
KPI Rank By Supervisor = VAR __ID = MAX(DIM_Employee_details[Supervisor_ID])
RETURN CALCULATE(RANKX(
     ALLSELECTED(DIM_Employee_details[emplid])
     ,([Overall_attainment]),,DESC,Dense),
ALLEXCEPT(DIM_Employee_details,DIM_Employee_details[Supervisor_ID],DIM_Employee_details[emplid]), DIM_Employee_details[Supervisor_ID] = __ID)
```

While applying this, I am getting the max rank for which overall attainment has values and 1 for which it has blank values.

| emplid | Employee_Name | Supervisor_ID | SUPERVISOR_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | IN087263 | Yash |
| 2 | B | IN087263 | Yash |
| 3 | C | IN087263 | Yash |
| 4 | D | IN087263 | Yash |

Comment: can you post the image of table with columns?

Comment: Don't post images here, post sample data instead.